# The ghost bar in the exetreme left

Tags: highcharts

When use Highstock we find there is a ghost bar in the exetreme left in the chart. There is no bar show on the chart, but when move the mouse to the exetreme left, it will show the data, and this bar will affect the yAxis and xAxis.

And we check the source code of the highstock, when user call the "setExtremes" and there is a method for processData, in this method have below logic:

```
// iterate up to find slice start
            for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                if (processedXData[i] >= min) {
                    cropStart = mathMax(0, i -1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // proceed to find slice end
            for (; i < dataLength; i++) {
                if (processedXData[i] > max) {
                    cropEnd = i + 1;
                    break;
                }

            }
            processedXData = processedXData.slice(cropStart, cropEnd);
            processedYData = processedYData.slice(cropStart, cropEnd);
```

we want to confirm this logic, why we need to do "**i-1**" and "**i+1**"?
And we try to override this method, it will cause the navigator bar not working well.

Is there any way that we can used to resolve this problem for the ghost bar in the exetreme left?

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, please. Crop is used by [cropThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.cropThreshold).

Comment: This do not need jsFiddle, http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/ in the highstock demon, for the first demo, please try to move the mouse to the extreme left slowly, then it will show May 14 2013, and the bars on the chart shows is May 15 2013. the bar for May 14 is the ghost bar. And the issue is caused by that code. I try and find a solution by override the code of highstock, but I do not like it, hope highstock team can resolve this issue.

Comment: Reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1954) Thanks!